# Styling material UI components

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, css-modules

Not really a problem but something I’m not happy with. I'm using `react` + `typescript` + `css modules` + https://material-ui-next.com/. Problem is that when I need to style material ui components I have to use `!important` a lot. Question is if there is a way to create styles without `important`. I create a sample project to reproduce the problem https://github.com/halkar/test-css-modules

Comment: Are you using Angular? Try `::ng-deep{}`

Comment: @John check the tags ;)

Comment: [Here's some documentation from the website about overriding styles, have you looked though it?](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/)

Comment: Yes. I've tried several different approaches from https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-class-names but all of them force me to use `!important`

Comment: Any luck with this? I also am strongly against css in js - it's awful.

Comment: @CasparHarmer check out my answer below. JssProvider fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should've used `JssProvider` and tell it to put material UI styles before mine in the page `head` section.

```
import JssProvider from 'react-jss/lib/JssProvider';
import { create } from 'jss';
import { createGenerateClassName, jssPreset } from 'material-ui/styles';

const generateClassName = createGenerateClassName();
const jss = create(jssPreset());
// We define a custom insertion point that JSS will look for injecting the styles in the DOM.
jss.options.insertionPoint = document.getElementById('jss-insertion-point');

function App() {
  return (
    <JssProvider jss={jss} generateClassName={generateClassName}>
      ...
    </JssProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Documentation on the above solution - https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order

Answer (score 5):

material-ui exposes many of their components for styling. There two ways to go about doing this.

### Apply styles globally

You could style the components globally and apply it to the theme. An example of this would be something like this (copied from the docs http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes):

```
import React from 'react';
import {cyan500} from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';

// This replaces the textColor value on the palette
// and then update the keys for each component that depends on it.
// More on Colors: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/colors
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: cyan500,
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 50,
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // MuiThemeProvider takes the theme as a property and passed it down the hierarchy
    // using React's context feature.
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <AppBar title="My AppBar" />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

As you can see in here, appBar component have a height of 50px meaning that every time you add an appbar component to your app down the tree where you applied the `muiTheme`, it will give it a height of 50px. This is a list of all the styles you can apply for each component https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js.

## Apply styles using style attribute

To apply the styles to individual components, you can usually use the style property and pass it the styles you want.

This is another example from the docs where a margin of 12px is applied to a RaisedButton.

```
import React from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

const style = {
  margin: 12,
};

const RaisedButtonExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <RaisedButton label="Default" style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Primary" primary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} style={style} />
    <RaisedButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} style={style} />
    <br />
    <br />
    <RaisedButton label="Full width" fullWidth={true} />
  </div>
);

export default RaisedButtonExampleSimple;
```

Now, the styles are defined in the same file but you could define them in a separate file and import them to the file where you are using the components.

If you want to apply multiple styles then you can use the spread operator like so: `style={{...style1,...style2}}`.

Usually, you are styling a specific thing in the component (root element) with the style property but some components have more than one property to style different elements of the component. Under properties in this page http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button, you can see that there are style property, labelStyle and rippleStyle to style different parts of RaisedButton.

Check the properties under the component that you are using and see which style property you could use, otherwise check the available global style properties you could override. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but my question was "how can I style material-ui components with css-modules?" I'm strongly against CSS-in-JS.

Answer (score -3):

you have to use the component API's. You can't set style to the components imported from libraries just with css if the component has API's to get style.

*Update

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    borderRadius: 3,
    border: 0,
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .30)',
  },
  label: {
    textTransform: 'capitalize',
  },
};

function Classes(props) {
  return (
    <Button
      classes={{
        root: props.classes.root, // class name, e.g. `classes-root-x`
        label: props.classes.label, // class name, e.g. `classes-label-x`
      }}
    >
      {props.children ? props.children : 'classes'}
    </Button>
  );
}

Classes.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Classes);
```

Comment: Problem is that I don't see how I can use their API with css-modules without `!important` https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-class-names

Comment: look at the documents and read the sample codes to know about how you can use their API's.

Comment: even if you want to add class to the component in this case you can use the `classes` API.

Comment: the answer updated, it's contain an example of overriding the style by class

Comment: Did you try your sample? Still, it will require `!important`. You just copy-pasted a sample from their website.

Comment: something is wrong in your component or css configuration, just because of that this API's implemented to do what you want without `important`, please check your lib version or something like this.

Comment: i use this material components in my project and i haven't any problem with the custom css style to it's components. you can check the [link](https://harzaan.com)

Comment: Read my answer above. Everything is correct in my app but I need to force `JssProvider` to put its styles before mine.